# Break a string into substring with delimiter as :

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have a string which i like this `string s = "09:04:31 00358800917204 FINLAND 00:00:16 2 1.56 21:18:32 00358800917204 FINLAND 00:00:16 2 1.56";`.Now as per my requirement i have to break this string into two substring like ..

```
string substring1 = "09:04:31 00358 FINLAND 00:00:16 2 1.56"

string substring2 = "21:18:32 00358 FINLAND 00:00:16 2 1.56"
```

How to break it like this ..Please help me ..Thanks..

Comment: So what are the rules for the delimiter?

Comment: Put your attempt in your question please.

Comment: @TimSchmelter All the rules that we can apply to effectively break into substring is Open for this ..

Comment: @ShivamShlom: why is there no separator like `Environment.NewLine` between?

Comment: We are looking for some pattern to understand how do you want to divide the string. Do you have 6 fields (time, code, country, time, code, decimal) separated by a space and the a new substring begins?

Comment: will 1.56 be always there at end of one string ?

Comment: @Steve Ok It is the `third :` where the new line begins and we need to break it into new subtstring

Comment: @TimSchmelter It is the third : where the new line begins and we need to break it into new subtstring

Comment: There's no consistency between what you're asking and what you want the output to be. Splitting on the 3rd `:` won't give you that outcome.

Comment: @DeeMac Ok Am sorry let me correct it.If i am dividing the string into string array based on space then the third array element which will conatin `:` onwards needs to be broken into second substring

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
var pattern = @"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s(\d*)\s(\w*)\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s\d\s\d*\.\d*";

string s = "09:04:31 00358800917204 FINLAND 00:00:16 21.56 21:18:32 00358800917204 FINLAND 00:00:16 2 1.56";

var rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var matches = rx.Matches(s);
```

This pattern works with your provided string, but might have to be changed according to your requirements. You can test it here: [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
\s(?=\d+:\d+:\d+(?:(?!\d+:\d+:\d+).)*?FINLAND)
```

You can split by this.Essentially it split by space which has `(time...FINLAND)` ahead of it.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/15